# How to find a acceleration of this formula? I just can't find its second derivative.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is the formula I am working on:

$$
\vec{\mathbf{y}}(t) = \left( R_E^{3/2} + 3tR_E \sqrt{\frac{g}{2}} \right) \hat{\mathbf{j}}
$$

This formula shows the location of rocket when launched from the earth surface. I need to find the acceleration of it. I have tried to calculate the second derivative myself and with online calculator, but none of them is correct.

I know the first derivative. But I have trouble looking for the second derivative in terms of g and RE, where g is gravity and RE is the radius of the earth ($6.38 \times 10^6$ m)

Comment: What happens when you compute the second derivative? Can you post your work? You are much more likely to get help here if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Have you tried to use say Wolfram Alpha? [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second+derivative+(R%5E(3%2F2)+%2B+3+Sqrt%5Bg%2F2%5D+R+t)%5E(2%2F3)+for+t) for example.

Comment: This formula looks off. You have a vector symbol over $y$, but the right hand side is not a vector. Is this the $y$ component of the position vector? Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), not images.

Comment: But there is an "RE" in this case, how can I plug it into wolfram alpha without any error?

Comment: What's so special about Re?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is a missing exponent in the question.
$$y(t)=\left(R_e^{3/2}+3\sqrt{\frac{g}{2}}R_et\right)^{2/3}$$
Set $a=R_e^{3/2}$ and $b=3\sqrt{\frac{g}{2}}R_e$. Then
$$y(t)=(a+bt)^{2/3}$$
$$y'(t)=\frac{2b}{3}(a+bt)^{-1/3}$$
$$y''(t)=\frac{-2b^2}{9}(a+bt)^{-4/3}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $R_E$ is a constant with respect to $t$, then 
$$
\begin{split}
\vec{\mathbf{y}}'(t)
 &= \frac{d}{dt} \left[\left( R_E^{3/2} + 3tR_E \sqrt{\frac{g}{2}} \right)
                       \hat{\mathbf{j}} \right]  \\
 &= \hat{\mathbf{j}}
    \left(\frac{d}{dt} \left[R_E^{3/2}\right]
         + \frac{d}{dt} \left[ 3tR_E \sqrt{\frac{g}{2}}\right] \right) \\
 &= \hat{\mathbf{j}} \left( 3R_E \sqrt{\frac{g}{2}}\right)
\end{split}
$$
which is also constant with respect to $t$, so $\vec{\mathbf{y}}''(t) = 0$.

However, if $R_E = R_E(t)$ also has 2 derivatives in $t$, you get
$$
\begin{split}
\vec{\mathbf{y}}'(t)
 &= \frac{d}{dt} \left[\left( R_E^{3/2} + 3tR_E \sqrt{\frac{g}{2}} \right)
                       \hat{\mathbf{j}} \right]  \\
 &= \hat{\mathbf{j}}
    \left(\frac{d}{dt} \left[R_E^{3/2}\right]
         + \frac{d}{dt} \left[ 3tR_E \sqrt{\frac{g}{2}}\right] \right) \\
 &= \hat{\mathbf{j}}
    \left(\frac{3}{2} R_E(t)^{1/2} \frac{d}{dt} \left[R_E\right]
         + 3t\sqrt{\frac{g}{2}} \frac{d}{dt} \left[ R_E\right]
         + 3 R_E(t) \sqrt{\frac{g}{2}} \right) \\
 &= \hat{\mathbf{j}}
    \left(\frac{3}{2} R_E(t)^{1/2} R_E'(t)
         + 3t\sqrt{\frac{g}{2}} R_E'(t)
         + 3 R_E(t) \sqrt{\frac{g}{2}} \right) \\
\end{split}
$$
Can you take another derivative?